# Unable to get source code for Other Git account using Azure Dev Ops pipelines

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gerrit, git-checkout

I believe Microsoft must have introduced a bug between Jan 16 and 17th in the pipelines. I'm wondering if others have experienced a similar problem and have found workarounds. 
Basically, I have a project, where nothing has changed, but the pipeline started to fail.

It fails when trying to fetch the code from git. Here's part of the log files when it was working, and currently.

**Log files: When it was working**

```
2020-01-16T03:00:26.2926085Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout
2020-01-16T03:00:26.2928221Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-16T03:00:26.2928417Z Task         : Get sources
2020-01-16T03:00:26.2928576Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-01-16T03:00:26.2928700Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-01-16T03:00:26.2928830Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-01-16T03:00:26.2928976Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-01-16T03:00:26.2929185Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-16T03:00:26.7775173Z Syncing repository: repository (ExternalGit)
2020-01-16T03:00:26.9327220Z ##[command]git version
2020-01-16T03:00:26.9728952Z git version 2.24.1
2020-01-16T03:00:26.9892738Z ##[command]git lfs version
2020-01-16T03:00:27.0835630Z git-lfs/2.9.2 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.1)
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1149634Z ##[command]git init "/home/vsts/work/1/s"
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1246583Z Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vsts/work/1/s/.git/
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1291339Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1395074Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1448215Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo.extraheader
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1508170Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1557498Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin https://***:***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1614885Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://***:***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-16T03:00:27.1744097Z ##[command]git fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-01-16T03:00:28.3617772Z remote: Counting objects: 1           
2020-01-16T03:00:28.3621364Z remote: Counting objects: 856, done        
2020-01-16T03:00:28.3622001Z remote: Finding sources:   1% (9/856)           
2020-01-16T03:00:28.3622483Z remote: Finding sources:   2% (18/856)           
2020-01-16T03:00:28.3622793Z remote: Finding sources:   3% (26/856)           
...
2020-01-16T03:00:28.3984234Z Resolving deltas: 100% (417/417), done.
2020-01-16T03:00:28.3984993Z From https://partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-16T03:00:28.3985319Z  * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4871619Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/origin/master
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4874383Z Note: switching to 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4874483Z 
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4874774Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4874905Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4875039Z state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4875122Z 
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4875386Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4875732Z do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4875824Z 
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876049Z   git switch -c <new-branch-name>
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876123Z 
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876210Z Or undo this operation with:
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876265Z 
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876485Z   git switch -
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876536Z 
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876641Z Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876726Z 
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4876829Z HEAD is now at 6edf9ec Added special file for staging, removed landscape
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4877693Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin https://***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4880668Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-16T03:00:28.4914507Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout
```

**Log files: When it's not working**

```
2020-01-20T14:54:57.9988687Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout repository@master to s
2020-01-20T14:54:57.9990848Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-20T14:54:57.9991037Z Task         : Get sources
2020-01-20T14:54:57.9991189Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-01-20T14:54:57.9991357Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-01-20T14:54:57.9991441Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-01-20T14:54:57.9991585Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-01-20T14:54:57.9991775Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-20T14:54:58.4808374Z Syncing repository: repository (ExternalGit)
2020-01-20T14:54:58.6686429Z ##[command]git version
2020-01-20T14:54:58.7183612Z git version 2.24.1
2020-01-20T14:54:58.7275067Z ##[command]git lfs version
2020-01-20T14:54:58.8017234Z git-lfs/2.9.2 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.1)
2020-01-20T14:54:58.8365628Z ##[command]git init "/home/vsts/work/1/s"
2020-01-20T14:54:58.8462491Z Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vsts/work/1/s/.git/
2020-01-20T14:54:58.8510054Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-20T14:54:58.8651845Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2020-01-20T14:54:59.6862773Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo.extraheader
2020-01-20T14:54:59.6866098Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2020-01-20T14:54:59.6872351Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin https://***:***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-20T14:54:59.6878555Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://***:***@partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-20T14:54:59.6882565Z ##[command]git fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-01-20T14:54:59.6886270Z remote: Counting objects: 1           
2020-01-20T14:54:59.6886446Z remote: Counting objects: 856, done        
2020-01-20T14:54:59.6886701Z remote: Finding sources:   1% (9/856)           
...
2020-01-20T14:54:59.9019224Z Resolving deltas: 100% (417/417), done.
2020-01-20T14:54:59.9020439Z From https://partners.macadamian.com/gerrit/a/mdgateway-mdgdemo
2020-01-20T14:54:59.9020866Z  * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
2020-01-20T14:55:00.0065267Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force
2020-01-20T14:55:00.0067477Z fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
2020-01-20T14:55:00.0128473Z ##[error]Git checkout failed with exit code: 128
2020-01-20T14:55:00.0176542Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout repository@master to s
```

As you could see the difference between the two log files are (near the bottom) and it is when it's trying to do a "git checkout":

- git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/origin/master   (when it's working)
- git checkout --progress --force   (when it's not working)

Basically the agent is not trying to specify the branch name anymore (master in my case) when executing the git checkout command. So that's why it's not working. The only explanation I could come with is Microsoft has changed something in the git checkout task and introduced a regression. And right now, I don't see any workaround.

Thanks,
Stephane.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, Azure Devops has [multiple pipeline service degradation events](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history) recently, this could be the reason why you meet the above issue.

Some users met similar git checkout error:`Git checkout failed with exit code: 128`  around January 17.

In this similar [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/891579/git-checkout-error-reference-is-not-a-tree.html) on developer community forum, the user use github as remote repo, as a workaround ,he rerun the pipeline completely (using /azp run).This generally fixes the issue but is very time consuming.

This issue is under investigation now, you can vote in that ticket and add your situation as a comment to the feedback. If this problem persists after the event is fixed, our engineers will investigate further.